# asdf: how to specify loading of entire folder instead of each separate file

Tags: asdf

I have a asdf system definition like this:

```
(asdf:defsystem #:my-package
    :serial t...

    :components ((:file "package")
                 (:file "macros")..........
                 (:file "tests/test-debug")
                 (:file "tests/test-regression") ))
```

Instead of specifying each file in the folder tests separately, I would like to specify all the files in the folder tests. Something like tests/* or (:directory "tests")

Can that be done?

Answer (score 2):

In the asdf source repository, see contrib/wild-modules.lisp